# Does the series $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{[n/3]}}{\sqrt{\log n}}$ converges or diverges?

Tags: real-analysis

I have to study the series 
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{[n/3]}}{\sqrt{\log n}}$$ in which $[n]$ denotes the whole part of $n$.

I know that $$\left|\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{[n/3]}}{\sqrt{\log n}}\right| < \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left|\frac{(-1)^{[n/3]}}{\sqrt{\log n}}\right| = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}$$.

But $\log n<n \rightarrow \frac{1}{\log n}>\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$.

The sum $\sum_{n}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges, so$ \sum_{n}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}$ diverges.
I've tried with the other criteria but nothing. Can someone help me to understand?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why the index of summation is always unrelated to the summands?

Comment: You're right , sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a natural number $n$, write $n=3k+r$ where $k$ is a nonnegative integer and $r$ is one of the numbers $0,1,2$. Then $n/3=k+r/3$, so $[n/3]=k$. Every nonnegative integer $k$ produces three natural numbers of the form $3k+r$ where $r\in \{0,1,2\}$, so the sequence $[n/3]$, when $n$ runs over the natural numbers, is simply:
$$\{0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,\dots\}$$
Therefore, the sequence $(-1)^{[n/3]}$ is this:
$$\{1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,\cdots\}$$
that is, except for the first two $1$'s, it is a bunch of three-tuples of $\pm 1$'s in alternating signs.

Consider the sequence

$$A_N=\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^{[n/3]}$$

Then you can convince yourself that $A_N$ takes only finitely many values, which are $1,2,0,-1$. In particular, the sequence $A_N$ is bounded.

Since for $n>1$, $1/\sqrt{\log n}$ is a positive decreasing sequence tending to zero as $n\to\infty$, it follows from Dirichlet's test that the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{[n/3]}}{\sqrt{\log n}}$ is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're not familiar with Dirichlet's test: Let's ignore the first term. The sequence of signs is then $-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,$ $-1,-1,-1,\dots$ Thus the series is

$$\tag 1 -\frac{1}{\ln 3}-\frac{1}{\ln 4}-\frac{1}{\ln 5}+\frac{1}{\ln 6}+\frac{1}{\ln 7}+\frac{1}{\ln 8}-\frac{1}{\ln 9}-\cdots$$

Let $S_n$ be the $n$th partial sum of this series. Then

$$S_{3n}= \sum_{m=1}^{n}(-1)^m\left (\frac{1}{\ln 3m}+\frac{1}{\ln (3m+1)} + \frac{1}{\ln (3m+2)}\right )$$

Apply the alternating series test to see $S_{3n}$ converges to some number $A.$ Check that $|S_{3n}-S_{3n+1}|\to 0$ and  $|S_n-S_{3n+2}|\to 0.$ It follows that all three subsequences $S_{3n}, S_{3n+1}, S_{3n+2}$ converge to $A.$ This implies $S_n$ converges to $A.$ This is the same as saying $(1)$ converges to $A,$ and we're done.

Comment: It would be $S_{3n+3  }, wouldn't  it?

Comment: And $1/log n $is divergent

Comment: Take $n=1$ for example. Then $$S_{3\cdot 1} = S_3 = -\frac{1}{\ln 3}-\frac{1}{\ln 4}-\frac{1}{\ln 5}$$ and $$S_{3\cdot 1 + 1} = S_4 = S_3 + \frac{1}{\ln 6}.$$

I am using the fact that the *sequence* $\dfrac{1}{\ln n}\to 0.$